# MongoDb findByIDandUpdate not working

Tags: arrays, json, git, mongodb

I'm trying to keep adding appointments to this array inside of a JSON object. My JSON object looks like the following ...

```
{
 "_id": "travis@hotmail.com",
 "appointment": [
                 {
                     "date": "12/16/2015", 
                     "time": "8:40:44pm"
                 }
                ]
}
```

My code doesn't show an error in the git shell, but it doesn't add the item to the array, I have tried `db.findById(..),.insert(),.update()` and other methods and couldn't make them to work, but here's my code:

```
var SchemaApp = new mongoose.Schema({

        patientid    : String,
        appointment:[{
            date: String,
            time: String
        }]          
    });
var appointments = mongoose.model('appointment', SchemaApp);
app.post('/makeApp',function(req,res){
  var patient = req.body.appPatient;
  var date = req.body.dateApp;
  var hour = req.body.hour;
  var minutes = req.body.minutes;
  var time = hour+":"+minutes;
  appointment.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {"patientid": req.body.appPatient},
    {"$push":{
            "appointment":{
                "date": date,
                "time": time
            }
        }
    },{"new": true});    
 res.redirect("/admin");
);
```

if I print to the console the patient,date and time they show perfectly fine.I have also tried putting the properties without cotation marks, and having instead of patientid i had _id

Answer (score 0):

There are no patientid field in your data example, but you are trying to find document by that field. Try to add patientid field to your documents.

Comment: I have changed it in the document field and it made a new document like this `{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5675de3ae4b079d777756103"
    },
    "patientid": "travis@hotmail.com",
    "appointment": [
        {
            "date": "12/16/2015",
            "time": " 5:40:44pm"
        }
    ]
}` .... which didn;t even send the info that I wanted and made that new document. that only happens if I change _id for patientsid... but I should have it as _id for the correct sintax but my document doesnt get updated